# estimating the roots of $ \epsilon z^n + p(z)$

Tags: polynomials, perturbation-theory

I have a polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $n-1$ with known roots $z_1, \dots, z_{n-1}$.  How I add the monomial term $a z^n$.  What are the roots of

$$ p_1(z) = p(z) + \epsilon z^n $$

In terms of the roots of $\epsilon$ ?  For very small values $a \ll 1$ the roots original $n-1$ roots should not move very much.  Can we estimate to first order in $\epsilon$ ?  Where does the $n$-th root come from?

---

Similar problems:

- [Asymptotic expansions for the roots of $\epsilon^2x^4-\epsilon x^3-2x^2+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810031/asymptotic-expansions-for-the-roots-of-epsilon2x4-epsilon-x3-2x22-0)
- [Approximating the roots of $\epsilon^{2}x^{3}+x+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405783/approximating-the-roots-of-epsilon2x3x1?rq=1)
- [Solve $\epsilon x^3-x+1=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704309/solve-epsilon-x3-x1-0?rq=1)
- Search [[perturbation-theory] [polynomials]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perturbation-theory+polynomials?sort=votes&pageSize=30) in Math.SE

Answer (score 3):

If you divide $p(z)+\epsilon z^n$ by $z^n$, you get a polynomial $q(1/z)+\epsilon=0$.  This has a nonzero linear term because $p(z)$ was order $n-1$.  So there is a root of $1/z=O(\epsilon)$, and $z=O(1/\epsilon)$.  The $n$th root comes from $\infty$.
The change in the other roots depends on their multiplicity.  If a root has multiplicity $m$, then they are change by $O(\epsilon^{1/m})$ which is much greater than $O(\epsilon)$.  That is because the new polynomial is roughly $c(z-z_k)^m+\epsilon z_k^n =0$ near $z_k$.